# RayCast по Sprites

Tags: c#, unity3d

В проекте есть некий код для определения слоев

```
List<RaycastResult> results = EventSystem.current.Raycast (pointMouseBegin, LayerMask.NameToLayer ("SwipeActive"));

if (results.Count > 0) {
    Debug.Log ("Swipe count 1");    
    isClick = true;

}
```

скрипт:

```
public static List<RaycastResult> Raycast(this EventSystem system, Vector2 mousePosition, LayerMask layer)
{
    List<RaycastResult> raycast = new List<RaycastResult>();

    PointerEventData eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(system);
    eventDataCurrentPosition.position = new Vector2(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
    List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
    system.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);

    foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
    {
        if (result.gameObject.layer == layer)
        {
            raycast.Add(result);
        }
    }

    return raycast;
}
```

он работает только на `UI` в канвасе, на простом объекте с `Sprite` нет, что не так ?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [статью с хабра](https://habr.com/post/359106/), чтобы понять как и с чем работает `EventSystem`. Если кратко, то с объектами Unity UI ( с помощью Graphics Raycaster), а так же с 2d и 3d физикой (Physics 2D Raycaster и Physics Raycaster), таким образом, `EventSystem` не должен работать с простыми `Sprite`, только если вы не добавите к ним `BoxCollider`, либо `BoxCollider2d`.